# Symfony2 different configuration in different bundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have this configuration in `config.yml` for Swiftmailer:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username: xxx@gmail.com
    password: xxx
    delivery_address: xxx@gmail.com
    spool:
        type: file
        path: %kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool
    antiflood:
        threshold:            99
        sleep:                0
```

But I need have one configuration to one bundle and another configuration to another bundle.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well... You actually can get the mailer service inside your bundles and configure them in a way you need. Just get transport instance, configure its handlers and create new `mailer` instance with injecting configured `transport` there:

```
    $transport = $this->get('swiftmailer.transport');
    $transport->setHost('smtp.gmail.com');
    $transport->setEncryption('ssl');

    $handlers = $transport->getExtensionHandlers();

    $handler = $handlers[0];
    $handler->setUsername('');
    $handler->setPassword('');
    $handler->setAuthMode('login');

    $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

I've set some properties above assuming that you want to use `gmail` transport. In `vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/SwiftmailerBundle/DependencyInjection/SwiftmailerExtension.php` there is simple check for this transport:

```
    //...
    } elseif ('gmail' === $config['transport']) {
        $config['encryption'] = 'ssl';
        $config['auth_mode'] = 'login';
        $config['host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $transport = 'smtp';
    } else {
    //...
```

You can try to configure `spool` by getting its container (you have to do it before getting `mailer` service):

```
$this->getContainer()
    ->setParameter('swiftmailer.spool.file.path, '%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool');
```

But this filepath should be used by default. You just have to enable spooling:

```
$this->getContainer()->setParameter('swiftmailer.spool.enabled', true);
```

`antiflood` can be configured in the similar way:

```
$this->getContainer()->setParameter('swiftmailer.plugin.antiflood.threshold', 99);
$this->getContainer()->setParameter('swiftmailer.plugin.antiflood.sleep', 0);
```

Hope it helps